# Python, Appending string on each item on the list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, append

I have a code that concatenates a string 'lst' on each item of the list.

```
    i = 0
    lim = len(lst)
    while i < lim:
        lst[i] = 'lst%s' % (lst[i])
        i += 1
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Title should actually be "prepending string on each item"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will modify the original `lst` object:

```
lst[:] = ['lst%s' % item for item in lst]
```

or using the new style string formatting:

```
lst[:] = ['lst{}'.format(item) for item in lst]
```

Comment: Why is the use of slice assignment (`lst[:] =`) important here? Works without it for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension slice assignment:

```
lst[:] = ['lst' + x for x in lst]
```

Comment: You don't need to create a temporary list, just use a generator expression

Comment: @gnibbler using a generator expression still creates a temporary list

Comment: Oh darn - but surely that's just an implementation detail. It's still better to write what you really mean just in case the implementation improves

Answer (score 0):

Here is a map version

```
lst = map(lambda x: 'lst%s' % x, lst)
```

Comment: IMHO the only good `map` version is `map('lst{0}'.format, lst)`

Comment: Awesome :) I'm still stuck in python 2.4!!

Comment: @jamylak, I upvoted your comment because it's the _best_ map version, but I don't agree that there is a _good_ map version.

Comment: @shyam, The equivalent for 2.4 would be `map('lst%s'.__mod__, lst)`

Answer (score 0):

A map version for fun

```
>>> lst=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> map('lst'.__add__, lst)
['lstfoo', 'lstbar', 'lstbaz']
```

But more seriously, you can assign to a slice from a generator expression

```
>>> lst[:] = ('lst{}'.format(x) for x in lst)
>>> lst
['lstfoo', 'lstbar', 'lstbaz']
```